# Do Canadian citizens have to file Canadian income tax returns even when living abroad?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, canada, non-resident

American citizens are required to file taxes from abroad and to declare **all** world income.

Is something like this also a requirement of Canadians when not residing in Canada?  Does anyone have any information on this subject?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No — the U.S. is the only country that imposes such a requirement on its citizens. Eritrea is another country (the only other...) in the world which taxes non-resident citizens, but it is not a regular income tax.

Every other country in the world taxes by *residency* and not by citizenship.

Canadian citizens who no longer reside in Canada (i.e.: have permanently emigrated, can prove that they did, and are officially residents elsewhere) are only taxed on income from Canadian sources.

For more information see [Canada Revenue Agency: Non-residents of Canada](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/nnrsdnts/ndvdls/nnrs-eng.html).

Comment: So if Eritrea is another country that does this, maybe the first sentence shouldn't say "the U.S. is the **only** country" to do it.